# Any solution for firebase packages integration in flutter in MacBook m1 pro

Tags: firebase, flutter, apple-m1

I have a flutter project which is dependent on some firebase services like auth, db etc. It was working fine on mac mini (intel). But on my MacBook pro I can't build project for podfile error. It showing firebase issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct solution for the same. But there is a work around for resolving the Podfile related errors. Follow the steps below,

> Execute the below command to install ffi from the terminal,

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

> Then in the iOS folder of Flutter project execute the below command to install the pods. You have to run this command every time a new Flutter project is created and if it needs firebase.

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

> Finally run the application in the Android studio